# enable notification access using adb

Tags: adb, android-notifications

I have an application that listens to receiving notifications. After installation, I should enable notification access to it from Setting -> Security -> Notification Access

I install this app on an emulator and run it using ADB. But I don't know how to enable notification access setting for it using the command line in ADB.I saw [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187127/grant-notification-access-via-adb) and guess its general answer is right but I can not find the actual setting name. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4goz99/how_to_replace_some_secure_settings_actions_with/?st=jdt7yfi0&sh=0522b1d7)
just type :

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners %nlisteners:com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.service.ServiceNotificationIntercept
```

No spaces after listeners

.....

Comment: I have a rooted phone and i am trying same but seems to be not working any idea ? Here is my command: adb shell settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners %nlisteners: mypackageName/com.company.app.service.CallNotificationListener

Answer (score 10):

Since Android 9 the accepted answer is not working anymore. What worked for me was to use :

```
adb shell cmd notification allow_listener com.mypackage.app/com.mypackage.app.mylistener
```

Comment: confirmed working without root on Android Q TV emulator

Comment: can we use for two listener  and how can we reset this